# How to save a svm file in mexopencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, file-io, svm

So, I am about to train a classifier and needed to save the result from the classifier, in mexopencv.

```
hello  = cv.SVM;
hello.save('foo.xml')
```

My Matlab compiler crashes due to segmentation fault. [As far as I know](http://answers.opencv.org/question/13418/machine-learning-saveload-problem/) this is supposed to be the way in OpenCV. Is there any other way to save files trained via `SVM` in `mexopencv` ; or is this something to do with Matlab file writing option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact a bug in OpenCV itself, not mexopencv. You should [report it](http://code.opencv.org/projects/OpenCV/wiki/WikiStart#Creating-new-tickets)...

Here is a minimal C++ program to reproduce the bug:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Ptr<SVM> svm = new SVM();
    svm->save("svm.xml");

    return 0;
}
```

Running this under a debugger, I [located](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp#L2396) the offending code:

```
df_count = class_count > 1 ? class_count*(class_count-1)/2 : 1;
df = decision_func;

cvStartWriteStruct( fs, "decision_functions", CV_NODE_SEQ );
for( i = 0; i < df_count; i++ )
{
    int sv_count = df[i].sv_count;
    ...
}
```

At this point, the SVM model is untrained, and `df` is an uninitialized pointer. `class_count` equals `0`, but `df_count` gets set to `1`, hence `df[i]` (with `i=0`) causes an access violation...

I think this could be fixed as:

```
df_count = class_count > 1 ? class_count*(class_count-1)/2 : 1;
if (class_count == 0) df_count = 0;
```

Changing `df_count` to `0` during debugging, the program runs correctly and I get the following XML file:

#### svm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<my_svm type_id="opencv-ml-svm">
  <svm_type>C_SVC</svm_type>
  <kernel>
    <type>RBF</type>
    <gamma>1.</gamma>
  </kernel>
  <C>1.</C>
  <term_criteria>
    <epsilon>1.1920928955078125e-007</epsilon>
    <iterations>1000</iterations>
  </term_criteria>
  <var_all>0</var_all>
  <var_count>0</var_count>
  <sv_total>0</sv_total>
  <support_vectors></support_vectors>
  <decision_functions></decision_functions>
</my_svm>
</opencv_storage>
```

---

For now you could avoid the bug by **training** the model first before saving it to file :)

Comment: fwiw, the produced XML file cannot be loaded correctly! OpenCV will [throw](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp#L2536) an exception this time if you try to load it: `svm->load("svm.xml");` saying `"OpenCV Error: Parsing error (SVM model data is invalid, check sv_count, var_* and class_count tags)"`

Answer (score 1):

You can try [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/) which has a Matlab interface. It comes two functions to read and write in svm (`libsvmwrite` and `libsvmread`).